# Intellisense: command-line error: invalid macro definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I am having problem regarding intellisense :

> IntelliSense: command-line error: invalid macro definition:
>   _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES_COUNT =1  d:\Bharat\Max\CreateMatFile\createMatFile3\createMatFile3\createMatFile3.cpp

In my visual studio 2012 for c++ project. Anyone can help me out to resolve this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the space before `=1`.

Comment: how to edit. It seems readonly at property->configuration property - >c/c++ -> command line.

Comment: That's different from what you said in your question. From your question, I thought you had that macro defined in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem and I managed to remove the space before " =1" as follows:

1. Go to the "Property Manager": in the menu select "View" -> "Property Manager"
2. Navigate to your appropriate solution and platform (e.g. "Release | x64") and expand it to see the property sheets
3. Now search these property sheets for the wrong preprocessor settings as follows:
4. Right click on the property sheet and select "Properties"
5. Go for the preprocessor settings: "Common Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "Preprocessor"
6. Remove the missplaced space

In my configuration one of these property sheets had the wrong preprocessor setting with the additional space " =1".
I fixed it and voilà intellisense worked again!

Answer (score 2):

In case of error message

```
e0992 command-line error: invalid macro definition: _m_cee=001
```

problem was solved by:

1. Right click on the target project in "Solution Explorer" and select "Properties"
2. Go to section "Configuration Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "Command Line"
3. In an Additional parameters add an option "/Zc:twoPhase-"
4. Apply and rebuild the project.

Also will be helpful to see build log file $(IntDir)$(MSBuildProjectName).log
(Name can be redefined in "General" -> "Build Log File" configuration section)

PS: In case of using C++/CLI

Comment: I have added this description here because looking for a solution of this problem refers me to this issue.