# command line error: invalid macro definition: UTF-8

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

For unknown reason, all of my c/cpp files were shown an 'error' called **"command line error: invalid macro definition: UTF-8"**. This 'error' is denoted by VSCode at the beginning of **each file (no matter empty or not)** but does not affect compilation and execution at all, so I consider that the 'error' itself is probably an error of VSCode.

One confirmable fact is that this 'error' is not caused by the code itself. Another confirmable fact is that this 'error' is the same in files using different coded character set. All of my C files are encoded by GB2312 and all of my Cpp files are encoded by UTF-8.

I doubt that there is somewhere wrong in settings of VSCode, but I have not changed any settings in VSCode before the error occurred. I installed Visual Studio 2022 Community before the error occurred, and I do not sure whether it caused the problem or not.
I tried the solution given in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605275/intellisense-command-line-error-invalid-macro-definition) but the problem still remains unsolved.

A typical error message looks like this:

```
[{
    "resource": "/d:/Ilinov/Codes/C/test1.c",
    "owner": "C/C++",
    "code": "992",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "命令行错误: 宏定义无效: UTF-8",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 2
}]
```

In which the Chinese means **"command line error: invalid macro definition: UTF-8"**. Noticed that this file is encoded by GB2312 instead of UTF-8, it is incomprehensible why VSCode would denote the error as this.

After the problem occurred, VSCode could not automatically denote any variables in c/cpp files, which is the problem that bothers me most.

Comment: Did you try transcoding one of the C files from GB2312 to UTF-8 to check if the encoding is the source of this problem?

Comment: Please find and show us VSCode's log of compilation commands. I think I know *what* is happening (although not why); the log will confirm this.